# Envoy shows no healthy upstream

Tags: java, proxy, microservices, envoyproxy

I'm trying to build an envoy proxy by the help a [blog](https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/envoy-proxy-with-microservices/) and I'm getting a bit of problem there.

- First of all, the blogs fixes the ip address and also it wildcard matches with any URL keeping the only thing important as port but when I tried to run the URL `http://192.168.99.100:9901/` for admin commands as given in blog it was not opening while when I tried it with my IP, it ran successfully.
- And also, I'm having problem with opening the webpage of the person service or product service on browser either by `http://192.168.99.100:10000/person` that is provided in the blog or by using `http://<myip>:10000/person` both of them displays `no healthy upstream` in the browser and in postman and I've no idea regarding `no healthy upstream`.

I'm not using zipkins.

I've seen questions related to `no healthy upstream` but I couldn't find an answer that can solve this problem.

Please help.